# Phonegap iPhone/Android Template that only loads a website

Tags: cordova, mobile-application

I want to create a web based mobile app, but my customer insists it must be a native app. They don't understand that even if it's a native app, all the functionality it needs is web based.

I think I can give them what they want if I create a web based app then use phonegap to build a native app that simply loads the web app.

A few questions:

1. Is there a generic phonegap template like this available?
2. Does anyone know if Apple will have a problem with this type of app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. PhoneGap wraps web apps into a native apps. See any [PhoneGap tutorial](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501397/Tutorials) and [Getting Started](http://phonegap.com/start).
2. No problem. See [here](http://www.macstories.net/news/apple-phonegap-framework-is-ok-for-the-app-store/). More context in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/phonegap/iphone%2420app%2420store%2420reject%7Csort%3adate/phonegap/K-lGBGf2Pho/nskak9I-qjoJ).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the description of your question is confusing only for me. I don't get what does "build a native app that simply loads the web app" exactly mean, and it's better to understand the goal.

If it's a webapp represented in a HTML5+JS+CSS3 app (having business value and end-user features), it's fine (like Paul said). 
Some customers ask for "native webapps", which don't anything just opening the corporate website:) Apple - of course - rejects these kind of "apps", so you won't be able to publish it. (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)